# Do you need to add constraints in html, js, and css for resizing to different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am pretty new to html, js, and css. I was wondering if just. like in IOS development where auto layout is needed for different screen sizes and/or orientations if this is the case for developing a website.  I've looked around and seen things like margins and auto, but I'm not sure.  Is there any specific links or videos one could suggest to understand this concept so that no matter how the screen size is the contents on board will adjust.  Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile

This could be what you are looking for. You can set media queries to let content adjust to different screen sizes in CSS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet, and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)

Answer (score 0):

use media queries like this :

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1025px) and (min-height: 1366px) and (max-height: 1367px) {
.header { width: 90%; }
}